# List comprehension: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification

Tags: python, format, list-comprehension

I'm building a list of days as strings with a leading zero:

```
dates = ['{0:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 32)]
print(dates)

['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31']
```

Now I want to add just a string at the beginning corresponding to the desired year and month

If I do:

```
prefix = '202001'
dates = ['{}{0:02d}'.format(prefix, i) for i in range(1,32)]

ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification
```

I would like to understand why this is happening. I'm not sure I understand what the error is trying to tell me.

Of course I can achieve my result by just doing:

```
[month + i for i in dates]
['20200101', '20200102', '20200103', '20200104', '20200105', '20200106', '20200107', '20200108', '20200109', '20200110', '20200111', '20200112', '20200113', '20200114', '20200115', '20200116', '20200117', '20200118', '20200119', '20200120', '20200121', '20200122', '20200123', '20200124', '20200125', '20200126', '20200127', '20200128', '20200129', '20200130', '20200131']
```

But I want to understand why my first approach didn't work.

Comment: It's ambiguous what `{}` refers to when the next field is `{0}`. Either don't specify an argument number both times, or do specify an argument number both times.

Comment: use `{}{:02d}` or `{0}{1:02d}`

Comment: And if you use python version 3.6 or later, use f-string. `f"{prefix}{i:02d}"`

Comment: @deceze Why it's ambiguous? What else can it mean? There's a `format` with two arguments inside, so if there are only two `{}` there's no confusion of what they are, otherwise the syntax would be incorrect.

Comment: If Python starts to consume from the left, the first `{}` should obviously refer to the first argument. But then you're explicitly mentioning `{0}`, and now Python is confused. Even if this *could* be resolved logically, Python won't do so. This follows the same tradition as with passing a mix of named and positional arguments. It's just the way it is.

Comment: @deceze thanks. I think the linked answer does not answer my question. It is about ordered arguments, while mine is about formatting with a number of leading zeroes.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki leading zeroes have nothing to do with your problem - the problem is the `0` you put before `:02d` -it explicitly specifies "first argument to format". So your `{}` is replaced by the value of `prefix` **and** your `{0:02d}` is **also** replaced by the value of `prefix` (or rather, it would, if it was the right type), leaving `i` unreferenced by the format string.